# Get classpath for ijava jupyter notebook

Tags: java, jupyter-notebook

I would like to see the current classpath for a SpencerPark/IJava jupyter notebook. I'm expecting that this would include dependencies loaded through the loadFromPOM magic. However, when I do
`System.getProperties().get("java.class.path")` I only get `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/java/ijava-1.3.0.jar`. Is there a different command I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the magic command `%jars path/to/jar.jar` is what you are looking for, according to the author [IJava's author](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/issues/53#issuecomment-476648391)